# Rename multiple files by adding an incrementing number prefix

Tags: powershell

These are my original file names:

AAA.pdf

BCC.pdf

CCC.pdf

DDD.pdf

etc...

---

I would like my script to modify the name of the file by adding a prefix with incrementing numbers as well as keep the original file name at the end:

Document 1 - AAA.pdf

Document 2 - BBB.pdf

Document 3 - CCC.pdf

Document 4 - DDD.pdf

etc...

How would I go about this on Powershell?

---

This is what I have been trying so far:

I first navigate to the path where the files are.

```
$count=1; 
dir | %{rename-item $_-newname ("Document {0} - {1}" -f $count++, $_.name)}
```

Issue:

rename-item: Cannot rename because item at 'AAA.pdf-newname' does not exist.

Comment: You would start with the Get-ChildItem cmdlet to process each of the files and the Rename-Item cmdlet to change the name.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I would try EBGreen's suggestion and then if you are having issues update your question with your code. It is appreciated, if not expected, that you show some coding effort.

Comment: What are the issues exactly? I see that you should remove the `%` from the code you have there. It should work after that. Ahh... i see that was a pending edit. THis is dependant on your current directory which could be error prone.

Comment: The error comes up as:

rename-item: Cannot rename because item at 'AAA.pdf-newname' does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume the "issues" you are having is that errors resulting from not being able to locate the file. You should be using the fullpath to the file in your loop. You aslo need a space between the value and parameter `$_-newname`.

```psh
$count=1; 
dir "c:\temp" | %{rename-item $_.FullName -newname ("Document {0} - {1}" -f $count++, $_.name)}
```

But you can update this code a little bit to the point where you dont need the foreach loop or need to specify the input file and instead work with the pipeline directly.

```psh
$count=1; 
dir "c:\temp" | rename-item -newname {"Document {0} - {1}" -f $count++, $_.name}
```

Comment: But if I navigate to the path first then execute the script, do I still need to include the path in my loop?

Comment: @Kat No you don't need it at all. Just a suggestion. Feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This uses more lines but I believe it's what you're after. Assumes files are in a subdirectory "files".

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "$PSScriptRoot\files"

$i = 1
foreach ($file in $files){
    $newname = "Document $i - " + $file
    Rename-Item $($file.FullName) $newname
    $i++
}
```