# Powershell: how to change format of sequential numbers in filenames by batch renaming?

Tags: powershell, filenames, batch-rename, sequential

How can you reformat the way filenames are numbered in a list of filenames using Powershell? Is there a better way than what I'm currently trying?

Example:
`01. name1.txt` -> `1.01 name1.txt`
`02. name2.txt` -> `1.02 name2.txt`
...
`100. name100.txt` -> `1.100 name100.txt`
`101. name101.txt` -> `1.101 name101.txt`
and so on...

Basically I want to:

- change `XX.` to `1.XX`
- leave the rest of the filename the same
- keep the order of files the same

---

I can run [this](https://superuser.com/a/273220) to remove the first few characters of then filename, but I'd have to run it twice for the 2-digit and 3-digit numbers. (results in `01. title1.txt` becoming `title1.txt`)

```
gci *.txt | ren -newname { [string]($_.name).substring(4) }
```

Then I could append the `1.XX` with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68772603/20802632). (results in `title1.txt` becoming `1.01 title1.txt`)

```
$count=01;
gci | rename-item -newname {"1.{0:d2} {1}" -f $script:count++, $_.name}
```

But it would be preferable to run a single command instead of 2 or 3. It would need to replace `XX.` with `1.XX` by keeping the `XX` variable, adding the `1.`, then removing the period that follows the variable.

Comment: related: [Rename multiple files by adding an incrementing number prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342469/rename-multiple-files-by-adding-an-incrementing-number-prefix)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to prepend `1.` and remove the `.` after the initial digits this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(^\d+)\.', '1.$1' }
```

See https://regex101.com/r/gMx9su/1 for details.